# Could a person parse a value from a php page to an external java script page?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to read a field value from a mySql database, such as username. After I have stored the field value in a php variable ($username), it works perfectly. The problem that I am having is to send that username value from the current php to an external java script page for further processing. So the question is, is there a simple way of me doing it? If I include a script tag within the php page, it just does not execute at all?

Any help would be much appreciated

```html
     echo '<script type="text/JavaScript">  
     setName("Andrew"); 
     </script>';
```

```js
function setName(line) {
    document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = getName(line);
}

function getName(line) {
    return line;
}
```

Comment: Make sure your external JS file is being loaded before your echo the script tag in your PHP.

Comment: use of  ```element.innerHTML="some html with script"``` will not work. it is blocked as security hole. just use fetch() or ajax to get the data and process it as you want.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately we are not allowed to use ajax for this assignment so it's kind of a bummer.

Comment: I did load the js file at the very top of the page, inside the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your echoed script has to be executed AFTER the element with the id `user` has been parsed. You have multiple ways to achieve this.

1. Echo your script anywhere after you element with the id `user`. - At best right before the `</body>` (common practice).
2. Let JS tell you, when the DOM has been loaded (place this JS whereever you like):

   ```
   window.addEventListener ('load', function () {
       setName("<?= $phpVariable ?>"); 
   });
   ```

Example:

```html
<script>
    console.log('Test script-tag before');
    console.log(document.getElementById('selectMe'));
    
    window.addEventListener ('load', function () {
      console.log('Listen for load-event');
      console.log(document.getElementById('selectMe'));
    });
</script>

<div id='selectMe'>Select Me</div>

<script>
    console.log('Test script-tag after');
    console.log(document.getElementById('selectMe'));
</script>
```

Comment: That sorted out my problem, thank you very much. I changed it a bit, but your concept helped me solve it, thanks.